# Why does vs code extension prettier not work?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, format, prettier

When I press CTRL+S for saving the HTML document,prettier does not format the text.And shows an exclamation mark at the bottom of the screen on the blue part.What could be the reason for this and how do I actually fix this?[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWjZ4.png)

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiTQY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do click on the exclamation mark, it would show you a log of what the issue is, then share the image here